# Can uniplate's `universeBi` be used to retrieve nodes in a breadth-first fashion?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, uniplate

Is it possible to use Uniplate's `universeBi` to get the output in breadth-first-order? It appears the results are returned in a depth-first fashion. I'm wondering how I can use uniplate to retrieve the `universeBi` in a breadth-first fashion.

To illustrate, consider the following toy program:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data

data A = A B Int deriving (Data, Typeable)
data B = B Int   deriving (Data, Typeable)

val :: A
val = A (B 1) 2

ints :: [Int]
ints = universeBi val
```

I get:

```
*Main> ints
[1,2]
```

But this is depth-first, as `1` is obtained from the `B` node. I'd rather get it in the breadth-first order, i.e., receive `[2,1]`. Is this achievable in uniplate?

Comment: this doesn't seem supported by uniplate, but it's possible with the lower-level `Data.Data`/syb

Comment: I don't think you're observing depth-first-ness here, just left-to-right-ness. The default instance of `Biplate` for a product type is roughly (pseudocode) `biplate (x, y) = concatTraversals (biplate x) (biplate y)`. If you switch the order of `A`'s fields you should get the `Int`s in a different order.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Left-to-right traversal is a form of depth-first traversal (in-order traversal)? The example isn't particularly illustrative, but I'm assuming OP would want a a function that could perform breadth-first traversal on `data Tree = Branch Tree Int Tree | Leaf`. No rearrangement of the arguments of `Branch` will make `universeBi` work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dig into the structure of the `Str` returned by `biplate`:

```
layers :: Str a -> [[a]]
layers Zero = []
layers (One x) = [[x]]
layers (Two f x) = catLayers (layers f) ([] : layers x)
  where catLayers [] ys = ys
        catLayers xs [] = xs
        catLayers (x : xs) (y : ys) = (x ++ y) : catLayers xs ys
layersBi :: Biplate from to => from -> [[to]]
layersBi = layers . fst . biplate
breadthBi :: Biplate from to => from -> [to]
breadthBi = concat . layersBi
```

So now

```
breadthBi (A (B 1) 2) :: [Int]
-- = [2, 1]
```

and

```
data Tree a = Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a) | Leaf deriving (Data, Typeable)
--       4
--   2       6
-- 1   3   5   7
example = Branch (Branch (Branch Leaf 1 Leaf) 2 (Branch Leaf 3 Leaf)) 4 (Branch (Branch Leaf 5 Leaf) 6 (Branch Leaf 7 Leaf))
(layersBi :: Data a => Tree a -> [[a]]) example
-- = [[],[4],[2,6],[1,3,5,7]]
```

I'm not sure if it's actually guaranteed that `Str` exactly reflects the structure of the data type, but it appears to. You could instead cook something out of the `Data` primitives if you have to.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a solution that didn't require looking "inside" the encoding, but it appears that is simply not possible.